# ExpandableListView - How to keep just one group child highlighted?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

How do I deselect all other child views that were selected? I'm trying to maintain just one child highlighted at any given time. In the code below, I'm able to to highlight the child but any other child I select within that group stay highlighted. Also, if I select one child and switch group, the next group child in the same position will be highlighted as well.

```
 //CHILD CLICK LISTENER
 lstRoute.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                //DO NOTHING
            }else
            {
                child.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    }
});

 //GROUP EXPANDED
lstRoute.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        //Only allow one group to be expanded at a time
        if (lastExpandedPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
            lstRoute.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
        }
        lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;

        //Clear all selections
        for(int i = 0; i < lstRoute.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View child = lstRoute.getChildAt(i);
            if(child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                child.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100,139,213,252)); //Light Blue
            }else{
                child.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView`s recycle views. That means, if a view gets hidden in one group, it will be used in the newly opened group.

Generally speaking: Highlighting a selection in `ListView`s should not be implemented in `ClickListener`s, but in a custom `Adapter`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, It pointed me in the right direction but can you provide an example of how this will work on a custom view?

Comment: https://github.com/F43nd1r/Multitool/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/faendir/lightning_launcher/multitool/scriptmanager/ScriptListAdapter.java while this is multiselection which also allows selecting groups, it should show the principle. (code by me)

Comment: Where are you utilizing `isSelected`, `getSelectedPackedPosition()` and `select()`?

Comment: In https://github.com/F43nd1r/Multitool/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/faendir/lightning_launcher/multitool/scriptmanager/ScriptManagerFragment.java

Comment: Got everything setup, thank you again for that source. Helped me out.